# JavaScript - Uncaught TypeError when trying to get info from DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror, undefined-behavior

Very new to javascript and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Trying to assign the `className` of a `<div>` element to a `var`, and I get this error.

```
scripts.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at checkWinner (scripts.js:30)
    at HTMLDivElement.buttonClick (scripts.js:25)
```

When I try to figure out if the property even exists, the console is leading me to believe it does. This seems like conflicting info to me.

winLines[0][0].className

```
"xButt"​
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm sure it's something basic. Here's the code just in case.

```
var turns = 0;
var gameButtons = Object.values(document.querySelectorAll('.gameButton'));
var winLines= [
  [gameButtons[0], gameButtons[1], gameButtons[2]]
  /* other arrays go hear */
];

for (let i = 0; i < gameButtons.length; i++) {
  gameButtons[i].textContent = null;
  gameButtons[i].addEventListener('click', buttonClick);
}

function buttonClick(e) {    
  console.log(e.target.id + ": You clicked me!");
  if (turns % 2 == 0) {
    e.target.className = 'xButt';
    e.target.textContent = 'X';
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    e.target.className = 'oButt';
    e.target.textContent = 'O';
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }
  turns++;
  checkWinner();
}

function checkWinner() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= winLines.length; i++) {
    let markOne = winLines[i][0].className;
    let markTwo = winLines[i][1].className;
    let markThree = winLines[i][2].className;
    if (markOne === markTwo && markOne === markThree) {
      alert("Awww sh********t!");
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, can you add just the code necessary to reproduce your problem? Like a [mcve] (maybe including the html where is the `.gameButton` elements

Comment: If you are plugging `winLines[0][0].className` in the console and it works, that suggests it's a timing issue.  Just because the value exists when you plug it into the console, doesn't mean it exists with the code runs.  You need to use some `debugger;` statements to examine your process closer in action

Comment: Do you run this JS code after your HTML code or call it in `header`?

Comment: Just noticed this part.

Comment: @CalvinNunes I tried to cut out as much fluff as possible, but since I'm not exactly sure where the error was occurring, I wasn't sure what else to cut.

Comment: @Taplar: someone helped me out. It was an array iteration error.

Comment: @KamNadimi I do a `defer` call in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop has more iterations than your array has elements.

Change the loop like so:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < winLines.length; i++)
```

The undefined error comes because you're trying `winLines[1][0]` which doesn't exist because `winLines` only has one element (at index 0)